# If the running time of the algorithm is T(n) = O(n log n) when n is the input size, what is the running time of the algorithm for T(m) when m = n^2?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

An algorithm takes input as an n × n Boolean matrix A. If the running time of the algorithm
is T(n) = O(n log n) when n is used as the input size parameter, then what is the running time of the algorithm for T(m) when m = n<sup>2</sup>?

This is how I solved it.

T(m) = m log m
log m = log n<sup>2</sup> = 2 log n and m = n<sup>2</sup>
T(m) = n<sup>2</sup> * 2 log n
T(m) = O(n<sup>2</sup> log n)

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. Simply substitue `M` for `N^2` and evaluate the expression, like you've done above.

```
O(N^2 log(N^2))
= O(N^2 2 log(N))
= O(N^2 log(N))
```